# "Lack of" vs "shortage of"

Tags: word-choice

> The plants have shut down for lack of funds.

Why can we not say:

> The plants have shut down for shortage of funds.

I can not tell the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite an interesting question. I'm sure the vast majority of native speakers would agree that in the *exact* context, ***for*** is far more acceptable followed by ***lack*** than by ***shortage***.

Given Google Books claims over 15,000 written instances of [***dismissed for lack of evidence***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dismissed%20for%20lack%20of%20evidence%22), it's hard to see how anyone could justify claiming ***for*** can't validly be used in such contexts. And I really can't be bothered to get bogged down in pedantic differentiation between ***owing to*** and ***due to*** - look that up elsewhere if you're interested.

---

It's worth pointing out that Google Books has just one readable instance of [***closed for shortage of funds***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22closed%20for%20shortage%20of%20funds%22), compared to an estimated 5060 hits for [***closed for lack of funds***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22closed%20for%20lack%20of%20funds%22), so it's hardly "a matter of opinion" that there's something "wrong" with the former.

Having said that, my own opinion is that this is a fairly extreme example of a *particular* sequence of words *(**for lack of X**)* having become so idiomatically established that we're still happy to use it even though the construction has fallen out of use in other contexts. And it really *was* quite popular and natural, as reflected by the [well-known proverb/ditty...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Want_of_a_Nail)

> *For want of a nail the shoe was lost.
>
>   For want of a shoe the horse was lost.
>
>   For want of a horse the rider was lost.
>
>   For want of a rider the battle was lost.*
>    ...

...where [*For **lack** of a nail the shoe was lost*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22For%20lack%20of%20a%20nail%20the%20shoe%20was%20lost%22) is a far from unknown variant.

---

The use of ***for*** as a direct replacement for ***because of*** has declined significantly over the centuries - probably because English has become increasingly reliant on using different prepositions to reflect different *meanings*. And in respect of "explanatory" clauses, ***for*** has largely settled on the sense of ***in order to*** ("internal" purpose) rather than ***as a consequence of*** ("external" reason).

But we've clung tenaciously to the very well established ***for lack of*** sequence - in which context it's worth noting that after ***a***, [the next most common word following those three is actually ***evidence***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20lack%20of%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfor%20lack%20of%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20funds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20space%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20evidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20money%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20any%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cfor%20lack%20of%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20a%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20knowledge%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20funds%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20space%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20evidence%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20food%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20time%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20money%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20lack%20of%20any%3B%2Cc0) (and wouldn't you know it, the *third* most common word is ***funds***!). I could speculate that this "unusually strong retention" is partly because it's long been common in *legal* contexts (which are particularly resistant to change). But that really is just "idle speculation".

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that [***owing to a shortage...***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=due+to+a+shortage+of%2Cowing+to+a+shortage+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdue%20to%20a%20shortage%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cowing%20to%20a%20shortage%20of%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdue%20to%20a%20shortage%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cowing%20to%20a%20shortage%20of%3B%2Cc0) was about as common as ***due to*** until WW2 (actually, *more* common in BrE). But there's been a massive shift since then (I did say "Don't get me started on that one! :)

Comment: I'd like to hope almost the *entirety* of my answer is irrelevant to the ***due to / owing to*** choice! That wasn't the *question*. I don't think OP is particularly interested in the difference between ***lack*** and ***shortage*** per se either - except insofar as this seems to have a huge effect on whether or not we can naturally use ***for*** in the sense of ***because of , due to, owing to, on account of***. And hopefully, the reason for that difference is what I've addressed.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is not large, but "lack of" would suggest that there are no funds at all (or none left) while "shortage of" suggests that there are some funds but not enough.

Comment: Sorry, but I think that difference is significantly less than "not large". In any case, it has no relevance at all in terms of explaining why OP's version #1 is common as muck, whereas his #2 is virtually unknown.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the accepted answer shoes that ther is a vast difference in frequency of use, but says nothing about why either.

Comment: That's because the vast difference in frequency of use is just a matter of ***what has become idiomatically established*** - it's nothing to do with the supposed semantic distinction between ***lack** (non-existence)* and ***shortage** (insufficiency)*. In purely practical terms, *The project was cancelled due to lack of interest* wouldn't really make sense if "lack" meant *total absence* (how could the project ever have started in the first place if *no-one cared about it at all*?).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Fair enough. So much of the curernt shape of language is the result of historical accident, and this is one more example of that.

Comment: It was a while ago now, but putting aside any possible *semantic* distinction between ***lack*** and ***shortage*** (which I don't think is relevant, even if there's a "grain" of truth in your point), I still think it's curious that if we use ***owing to*** or ***due to***, both nouns seem *syntactically* fine (it's just that *[owing / due to] [a] **shortage** of funds* is very much less likely). But whereas *closed for lack of [necessity]* seems perfectly natural to me, *closed **for shortage** of something* just feels to me like it's "ungrammatical", rather than simply "unidiomatic".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see your point, and it is interesting.  I wonder if "shortage" seems to go better with "count" nouns. "The building stopped for shortage of concrete" seems natural, but "The army halted for shortage of courage" does not, while "lack of courage" does, at least to me.

Answer (score -1):

I think part of the issue is that "funds" is a difficult example, because it is a word ending in "-s" (which usually signifies plural), but in fact doesn't specify a singular or plural (you would not say "one fund/many funds" here, although there are contexts like *investment funds* where you can say this, the word is used differently for that).

Suppose we use a different word, in the same sentence, to make this clearer:

- "The building was not completed because of **a shortage of bricks**."
- "The building was not completed because of **a lack of bricks**."

Here the difference is easier to see. A shortage means literally, there was insufficient supply/availability. A lack means there were none at all.

Answer (score -1):

The plants have shut down **due to a shortage of funds.**

The plants have shut down **due to a lack of funds.**

You can say both but not with "for".

I agree with my colleague who says **shortage** means **not enough**. I also think shortage is best used with things like food or supplies, and not with the word fund.

Please note: "due to a shortage of funds" is very common.

The term "a shortage of funds" is very common". But not this: x is closed "for a shortage of funds."

See for yourselves:

closed ***due to*** a shortage of funds

[closed due to a shortage of funds](https://www.google.com/search?ei=GU6VXKabAei1ggfc9qSAAQ&q=%22closed%20due%20to%20a%20shortage%20of%20funds%22&oq=%22closed%20due%20to%20a%20shortage%20of%20funds%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...17144.19230..19832...0.0..1.284.986.7j1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j33i10.nn6nj1rxkFQ)